# how to alert random texts upon clicking button in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have button, and i want to alert random text whenever i press the button. how can i do that?

this is what i have tried so far. it shows me nothing when it alerts.

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props)

            this.state = {
              notes: ['me', 'hi', 'you'],
              selectedNote: null,
              clicked: false
            }
          }

     handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({
          clicked: true, 
          selectedNote: this.state.notes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
    this.state.notes.length)]
        })
      }

onPressButton() {  
            Alert.alert(this.handleClick)  
        }  
render() {  
        return (  
            <View style={styles.container}>  
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>  
                    <Button  
                        onPress={this.onPressButton}  
                        title="You"  
                    />  
                </View>  
            </View>  
        );  
    }  
}
```

i need to alert the texts i specified randomly whenever i press the button

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you alerting `this.handleClick` function, you should alert `selectedNote` instead.

```
onPressButton = () => {
  const { notes } = this.state;
  const selectedNote = notes[Math.floor(Math.random() * notes.length)];

  this.setState({
    clicked: true, 
    selectedNote
  });

  Alert.alert(selectedNote);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but am still getting error, any other example

Comment: the error says: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.notes')

Comment: Updated `onPressButton` to be an arrow function, this should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use Faker for getting completely random names and stuff. Check [this](http://var%20faker%20=%20require('faker');%20%20var%20randomName%20=%20faker.name.findName();) out.

```
var faker = require('faker');

onPressButton = () => {
var randomName = faker.name.findName();
Alert.alert(randomName);
}
```